# Change of mysql timezone to my country timezone

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a project (php with mysql database) which is hosted on a server based in the united states and i've get the database to get the current time and date whenever a new insertion its done. what i realise is, its using the current time and date of the united states. How can i change the timezone of the database so it gets that of Ghana.

Comment: You can set the `GLOBAL` `timezone` to set timezone in mysql. check this out: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html